# Transform XML file to another XML file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I am trying to convert a xml file to another using XSLT. As I am a quite newbie to this please help me to create xslt to transform below input xml file to output xml file.
Thanks in advance.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<title>
    <subtitle1>
        <OrganizationDetails>
            <OrgName>qwe</EmpNumber>
            <OrgAddress>asdfg 123</EmpName>
        </OrginzationDetails >
    </subtitle1>
    <subtitle2>
        <ResourceDetails>
            <EmpNumber>1</EmpNumber>
            <EmpName>xyz</EmpName>
        </ResourceDetails>
        <ResourceDetails>
            <EmpNumber>2</EmpNumber>
            <EmpName>abc</EmpName>
        </ResourceDetails>
        <ResourceDepartment>
            <EmpNumber>1</EmpNumber>
            <DepartmentNo>IT</DepartmentNo>
        </ResourceDepartment>
        <ResourceDepartment>
            <EmpNumber>2</EmpNumber>
            <DepartmentNo>SALES</DepartmentNo>
        </ResourceDepartment>
    </subtitle2>
</title>
```

**Expected Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<title>
    <subtitle1>
        <OrginzationDetails>
            <OrgName>qwe</EmpNumber>
            <OrgAddress>asdfg 123</EmpName>
        </OrginzationDetails >
    </subtitle1>
    <subtitle2>
        <ResourceDetails>
            <EmpNumber>1</EmpNumber>
            <EmpName>xyz</EmpName>
        </ResourceDetails>

        <ResourceDepartment>
            <EmpNumber>1</EmpNumber>
            <DepartmentNo>IT</DepartmentNo>
        </ResourceDepartment>
    </subtitle2>
</title>

<title>
    <subtitle1>
        <OrginzationDetails>
            <OrgName>qwe</EmpNumber>
            <OrgAddress>asdfg 123</EmpName>
        </OrginzationDetails >
    </subtitle1>

    <subtitle2>
        <ResourceDetails>
            <EmpNumber>2</EmpNumber>
            <EmpName>abc</EmpName>
        </ResourceDetails>
        <ResourceDepartment>
            <EmpNumber>2</EmpNumber>
            <DepartmentNo>SALES</DepartmentNo>
        </ResourceDepartment>
    </subtitle2>
</title>
```

Comment: In general, you will want to utilize a [key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#key) in order to resolve the cross-references in your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The essence of the solution is

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/title/subtitle/*" group-by="EmpNumber">
  <title>
    <subtitle>
      <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution.It Works!!..I have just modified input xml with one more sub-element for root tag tittle.It would be a great help for me if you could help me how to incorporate the same with above solution..Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: Please do not change a question after it has been answered in such a way as to invalidate the answer. It makes things thoroughly confusing for people who come here later looking for an answer to a similar question. If you have supplementary questions, open a new question.

Comment: @Ajeet, I have no idea how the key function would be useful here.

Comment: @Michael Kay can be possible in key function